# How to show SnackBar In android for Pre-Lollipop Device?

Tags: android

I am in trouble i cant show Snackbar in android
**How to show SnackBar In android for Pre-Lollipop Device?**

Comment: Please google before asking questions on SO, search yields a ton of results on this topic.

Comment: sorry but....I used but it show classnot found exception thats why i asked this questions

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at the new [Material Design compatibility library](http://android-developers.blogspot.com.es/2015/05/android-design-support-library.html). It has the SnackBar for pre-lollipop devices.

Your gradle dependency is: `compile 'com.android.support:design:22.2.0'`

**EDIT**

If you are using eclipse, follow the instructions from the official page:

> After you download the Android Support Libraries, this library is located in the << sdk >>/extras/android/support/design directory. For more information on how to set up your project, follow the instructions in [Adding libraries with resources](https://developer.android.com/tools/support-library/setup.html#libs-with-res).

Comment: Sorry but i used Eclips

Comment: In this case you can download the jar and put it in the libs folder. This repository is public.